# Understanding reputation leagues

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

When I look at [my week user reputation](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/7/week/gaming/2017-02-26/172095#172095) it says I'm 0.81 on it at rank #4. I don't understand the stats that I see there:

[image: stats]

What do the different stats mean? I understand total reputation and week rank (I don't know how that's calculated) but +39 change from when? The start of the week? Today? And week reputation I believe is reputation gained since the start of the week?

And I notice now when I try to putt a tag in I must put one of the following listed. Am I writing on the correct stack exchange site to ask this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `+39`: the change in position. Since you are fourth this period (you've selected the week statistics, so the period is one week, starting on Sunday UTC time), your position the previous position was 43.
- `645`: your total reputation.
- `266`: the reputation gained in this period. That means your reputation at the end of the previous period was 379.

Comment: Thanks. Will accept in 3 mins :3

Comment: No hurry. Maybe someone else comes with a better answer.

Comment: You should celebrate. This is you 999th answer.

Comment: For real! I didn't see that yet. 

Comment: Also remember that `0.81` is top 0.81 percent...

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket I think bit more than 3 minutes have passed... more like 665280 minutes... ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh god. I don't even remember asking the question.

Comment: hehe, better late than never! @Exp